# IE10 stopping menu from working correctly

Tags: html, css, menu, internet-explorer-10

Please see a menu I'm using on a site below. It works fine in most browsers but with IE10 (IE11 is fine) when you hover over a menu item then go to select a sub menu item, when the cursor goes into any of the small gaps between the vertical sub menu items the menu thinks the user has went outside the submenu and it closes.

Can anybody tell me what is causing this to happen in IE10 and nothing else?

Regards,
Marc

```css
#nav-wrap {
 height:28px;
 position:relative;
 top:-70px;
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 z-index:10;
 text-align:center;
}

#nav {
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:400;
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
 display:inline-table;
}

#nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display:block;
}

#nav ul {
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
}

#nav ul:after {
 content:"";
 clear:both;
 display:block;
}

#nav ul li {    /* KEY - Changes main nav bar li style */
 float:left;
 margin-left:14px;
 margin-right:14px;
}

#nav ul li a {
 display:block;
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
 background:#416b8f;
 border-radius:2px;
 padding:3px 15px 3px 15px;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
 background:#003768;
 border-radius:0px;
 -webkit-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
    -o-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
    transition: ease-in 0.2s;
}

.selected {
 background:#003768;
 display:block;
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
 border-radius:2px;
 padding:3px 15px 3px 15px;
}

#nav ul ul {
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 text-align:left;
 margin:0;
 display:none;
}

#nav ul ul li {
 float:none;
 position:relative;
 margin:0px;
 font-size:14px;
 padding-top:1px;
 padding-bottom:1px;
 padding-left:2px;
}

#nav ul ul li:hover {
 
}

#nav ul ul li a {
 border-radius:0px;
 padding-top:5px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
}

#nav ul ul li a:hover {
 background:#003768;
 -webkit-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
    -o-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
    transition: ease-in 0.2s;
}

#nav ul ul ul {
 position:absolute;
 left:100%;  /* switch to left to change position of nested menus */
 top:0;
}

li {
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">ACET</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">ACET HELPS</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">ACCREDITATION</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">FEATURES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">WEB DASHBOARD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ACET 8</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CLIENTS</a></li>
                        <li class="selected">NEWS</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">TRAINING</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">HELP DESK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">USER GUIDE</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">ACET TECHNICAL PRACTICE</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">DATA IMPORT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DEVELOPMENT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">ASSET INTEGRITY</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">INTEGRITY INFORMATION</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">INSPECTION &amp; INTEGRITY MANAGEMENT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">NON-DESTRUCTIVE TESTING</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">SPECIALIST INSPECTION SERVICES</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">INSPECTION METHOD CAPABILITY</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">INSPECTION METHOD SELECTION</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">DATA SOLUTIONS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">DOWNLOADS</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">LATEST NEWSLETTER</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">ACET DATA SHEET</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">ASSET INTEGRITY BROCHURE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">THE INSPECTION STANDARD</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: I actially can't replicate this problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fo8maoq/). I'm using IE11 and emulating with `Doc Mode ie10` and `UA string ie10`

Comment: Using actual IE10 (10.0.9200.17377) this issue doesn't occur in the fiddle.